# Knex returns different responses when using local vs using on aws rds

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, knex.js

I have a question related to Knex.
Currently, I am using two versions for knex to connect to database.
One for local testing using these configurations

```
client: 'pg',

connection: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: process.env.AURORA_DB_USER,
    password: process.env.AURORA_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.AURORA_DB_NAME,
  },
```

And one for AWS RDS connection using these configurations

```
const knexDataApiClient = require('knex-aurora-data-api-client');

const configs = {
  secretArn: process.env.AURORA_SECRET_ARN ?? '',
  resourceArn: process.env.AURORA_RESOURCE_ARN ?? '',
  database: process.env.AURORA_DB_NAME,
  region: process.env.AURORA_REGION,
  host: process.env.AURORA_DB_HOST,
};

const knex: Knex = require('knex')({
  client: knexDataApiClient.postgres,
  connection: configs,
});
```

But i am facing a problem when fetching data using those two versions.
The body of response is different like the example below.
One is returning normal array and the other is an object containing the array

- fetching using local knex:

  "sectors": [
  "consumer",
  "growth"
  ]
- fetching using rds knex instance:

  "sectors": {
  "stringValues": [
  "enterprise",
  "growth"
  ]
  },

and some other cases

I need some help figuring out what is the problem here

Comment: Only reason I could think of is that aurora is returning data in a different format than pg. Check out how are the result objects if you do raw queries in both.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug in the knex adapter. Please create an issue on the github repo (https://github.com/markusahlstrand/knex-data-api-client) and I'll have a look at it.

Best,
Markus